How can i execute this command without needing to execute it manually everytime i open the EXE
i used pyinstaller to make an exe out of my python project. when i tried to execute the EXE file i encountered the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "prophet\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ERWIN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI188562\\prophet\\__version__.py'

i had encountered i warning of sorts during the pyinstaller process stating that "freezing modules" are being used an you can counter issues. it also mentioned you can pass the following command to python in order to disable this.
python -m main.exe -Xfrozen_modules=off

and this actually works. when i enter this command into CMD when executing the EXE the app runs properly. now i dont now what this "freeze module" thing is but what i know is that its pretty inconvenient to pass this command every time you want to open the app.
i also dont want to use any other things in order to fix this(for example a batch file) specifically because i want to turn this app into a setup.
i have tried changing the spec file, changing the code itself for it to execute this command automatically, even making a batch file. none of this works.
as always any help is appreciated.

The error says the __version__.py from prophet can't be found.
So actually you can directly include that file when you run the pyinstaller command.

Here are the steps:
1. Go to the site-packages folder and find the prophet package, you should be able to see the __version__.py in the prophet folder. Copy that.
2. In your project folder, create a folder named prophet and paste__version__.py into it.



3. Use--add-data command to inlcude the __versions__.py.
pyinstaller main.py --add-data "./prophet/__version__.py;prophet"
4. When you run the executable again, the FileNotFoundError for __version__.py should be solved. However, there might be FileNotFoundError for another file. You can solve the error with the same steps. If those files are all from prophet, then you can include the whole prophet package with --add-data command. You can visit pyinstaller's documentation to learn more about this command.
